# How is my internet browser able to write files into my "Downloads" file if the default permissions do not allow to "write"?

Tags: permissions

On the terminal, I used this command:

```
stat Downloads
```

It stated the permissions for my downloads folder were "drwxr-xr-x"

Wouldn't this mean only the admin and owner would be able to edit the folder?
How would the browser download something and put it in the folder if it does not have the permission, or does Ubuntu detect that you allowed the browser to do so?

Comment: I suspect that if you were to enter `ls -ld Downloads`  then you would discover that you are, in fact, the owner of your Downloads folder.  So, when you run your browser, it is you, as the directory owner, who is attempting to place something into that directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Programs run with the privileges of the user who invoked them.
So when you launch your browser, the browser process has the rights you have to read, modify and execute files.

And as you are the owner of your Downloads folder, your user account has (usually by default) full **`r`ead/`w`rite/e`x`ecute** rights. Therefore your browser has them too.

To clarify the *stat* output `(d rwx r-x r-x)`:

- The first letter (here: `d`) describes the **type of the file system object** you are examining. `d` means that you are showing the permissions of a directory. If you are examining a file, you will get a `-` instead. There are other possibilities too, like `l` for a link. Further there are (according to @Atsby's comment) `b` for block devices, `c` for character devices, `p` for pipes and probably even more...
  <sub>See * for note about directory permissions!</sub>
- The first three letters `rwx` stand for the **owner's permissions**. A letter means that the respective access type is granted, a "-" means denied. *--> full access*
- The second three letters `r-x` represent the **permissions** users have who are members of the **owner's group**. It's the same "rwx"-format as above. *--> only read and execute permissions, no writing*
- The last three letters `r-x` represent the **permissions of any other users** who is *not* the owner itself and is *not* a member of the owner group. Still same "rwx"-format. *--> also only read and execute permissions, no writing*

<sub>* Directory permissions:

Note that directory permissions have different meanings than file permissions. For directories...

**read access (r)** means *listing the files (`ls` command)*,

**write access (w)** means *changing the directory content (creating, deleting, renaming files)* and

**execute access (x)** means *entering the directory (`cd` command or opening with the file manager)*</sub>

---

**Advanced execute permissions:**

Sometimes you find an `S`, `s`, `T` or `t` where you would expect an `x`.

There are **SUID (Set User ID)** and **SGID (Set Group ID)** permissions which replace the normal `x` if the file should always be executed with the permissions of its owner (SUID) or its owner group (SGID). For SUID, the `x` of the user permissions (first block) gets replaced, for SGID, the `x` of the group permissions (second block) gets replaced. A capital letter `S` stands for a `-` (permission denied) while a small `s` equals to `x` (permission granted).

If the `x` of the third block (others' permissions) gets replaced by a `T`/`t`, this means that the **"Sticky Bit"** is set. Nowadays, it is mostly used to prevent deletion of the file by non-owner users who have write permissions. Again, a capital letter `T` equals a `-` (no execute permission for others) without "Sticky Bit", while a small `t` stands for granted execution access (`x`) for others.

---

**Octal notation:**

The permissions can also be represented by 3-4 digits (values 0-8), which is called octal notation.
Normally you have 3 digits or 4 digits with the first digit set to 0 (e.g. `755` or `0755`).

- The first digit (which can be omitted if it is 0) represents the advanced permission flags. Flag values: SUID=4, SGID=2, Sticky=1.
- The second digit represents the state of the owner's permission flags (rwx; first permission block in string formatting). Flag values: r=4, w=2, x=1.
- The third digit represents the state of the owner group's permission flags (rwx; second permission block in string formatting). Flag values: r=4, w=2, x=1.
- The fourth digit represents the state of all other's permission flags (rwx; third permission block in string formatting). Flag values: r=4, w=2, x=1.

To calculate the digit value, just sum up the flag values of all set flags. Examples: rwx=4+2+1=7, r-x=4+0+1=5

---

<sub>Source and additional references:

http://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1822622&seqNum=6

Please visit those links for more detail, especially about advanced permissions.</sub>

Comment: +1, `d` stands for `directory` by the way!

Comment: @kos Thanks, I will add this. What would the other possibilities be instead of a "d" in this place?

Comment: None, if it's not a directory it's indeed a file, so you always have either `d` or `-`

Comment: @kos there are other possibilities, for example `l` for a soft link, `b` for a block device, `c` for a character device, `p` for a pipe ... those are just the ones I know of, there are probably more

Comment: @Atsby You're right, I was talking about `ls` when indeed OP used `stat`

Comment: ByteCommander, perhaps you might want to rewrite the answer based on Atsby's informations

Comment: @Atsby No, i was just plain wrong, I tried `ls -l /dev` and it also listed other things among `d` and `-`. Sorry about that!