# could someone explain the outcome entries into a file?

Tags: command-line, permissions, ls

I have read a really good answer explaining what `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 523454 Aug 8 2014  name` means.

However, It did not explain the number before the `root root`. Also, could you explain what `lrwxrwxrwx` means, please?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/606564/367990) for a detailed explanation of the permission string (the "lrwxrwxr-x"-like thing).

Answer (score 0):

if the output of `ls -l` is

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 523454 Aug 8 2014 name
```

The number `1` refers to the number of hard links to that file. Hard links are basically just an additional name for an existing file or folder. For more info on hard links, visit [this site](http://www.linfo.org/hard_link.html). You can view [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43047) for more information

`lrwxrwxrwx` refers to a link that can be read, written and executed by the owner, group and others.